# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE. App crashes due to this

Tags: android, firebase, quickblox-android

Crash log -

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2023-03-03 15:33:10.259 11639-12705/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process:  PID: 11639
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:381)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:250)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:402)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:672)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:659)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.zzm.<init>(Unknown Source:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager.zzd(Unknown Source:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager.schedule(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeTaskManager.a(Unknown Source:58)
        at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.c(Unknown Source:24)
        at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.a(Unknown Source:150)
        at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.a(Unknown Source:136)
        at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.e(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.b(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeService.onHandleWork(Unknown Source:51)
        at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:396)
        at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(JobIntentService.java:387)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            ... 3 more
2023-03-03 15:33:10.263 1768-2337/? E/OplusNetworkStackManager: callback len = 6
```

Root build.gradle -

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app:build.gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding false
    }


    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 109
        versionName "1.0.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            crunchPngs false // or true
        }
    }

}

//def qbSdkVersion = '3.7.0'
def work_version = "2.8.0"
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
//    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
//    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'
    constraints {
        implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0') {
            because 'play-services-ads depends on work-runtime:2.1.0 which is not compatible with targetSdk 31, but work-runtime:2.7.0 is'
        }
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.1"
    constraints {
        implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0') {
            because 'play-services-ads depends on work-runtime:2.1.0 which is not compatible with targetSdk 31, but work-runtime:2.7.0 is'
        }
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.1.0'
    constraints {
        implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0') {
            because 'play-services-ads depends on work-runtime:2.1.0 which is not compatible with targetSdk 31, but work-runtime:2.7.0 is'
        }
    }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.slice:slice-core:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.slice:slice-builders:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.9.2"
    //include only necessary module dependency, all transitive modules will be included automatically
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.9.2"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.9.2"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:3.9.2"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.9.2"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.9.2"
    implementation "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-conference:3.9.2"
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.hlab.fabrevealmenu:fab-reveal-menu:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.arthurghazaryan:floatingactionmenu:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.labo.kaji:relativepopupwindow:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.douglasjunior:android-simple-tooltip:0.2.2'
    implementation 'am.appwise.components:NoInternetDialog:1.1.3'
//    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.5'
    implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0')
//    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
//    implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.Kyash:android-target-instructions:0.1.4'
//    implementation(name: 'sinch-android-rtc', version: '+', ext: 'aar')

    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.+'
    implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.bogdwellers:pinchtozoom:0.1'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.22171'
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:BottomDialogs:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jineshfrancs:CaptchaImageView:1.0'
    implementation 'com.poovam:pin-edittext-field:1.2.3'

    def billing_version = '5.1.0'

    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.angads25:toggle:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:2.1.0'
//    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0'
//    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0'
//    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.0")


    // (Java only)
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version")

    // Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version")

    // optional - RxJava2 support
    implementation("androidx.work:work-rxjava2:$work_version")

    // optional - GCMNetworkManager support
    implementation("androidx.work:work-gcm:$work_version")

    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version")

    // optional - Multiprocess support
    implementation "androidx.work:work-multiprocess:$work_version"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService has PendingIntent as follows -

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE );
```

I was trying to upload new version to play store, it ask me to use sdk 31 to upload new version. After setting up sdk 31 then this pending intent crash is introduced. I have tried to add Work-runtime is not resolving the problem. App is crashing at random times with the same error message.

Comment: I have figured out why it is crashing, it is due to quickblox. When I login into quickblox services then it start crashing. If I do not login into quickblox services then it's fine. Now I need to contact quickblox for fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cost me a lot of time to figure out which library was culprit. It was QuickBlox in my case. I have updated QuickBlox to 4.0.3 and using work-runtime 2.7.1

Now my Build.gradle have following changes  -

```
implementation ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:4.0.3")
implementation ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:4.0.3")
implementation ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-customobjects:4.0.3")
implementation ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:4.0.3")
implementation ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-conference:4.0.3")
implementation ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:4.0.3")    
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
```

Crash is gone. Although I will have to rework on QuickBlox functionality as they have changed few things with updated library. Thank you everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

`PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` requires API level 23

Since your `minSdkVersion` is 20, you should perform the sdk check

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried this solution as well. But it is still crashing with same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should update minSDK to 23 and use following code for PendingIntent :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE || PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Now Build.gradle have following changes -

```
    // (Java only)
implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1")

// Kotlin + coroutines
implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1")

// optional - RxJava2 support
implementation("androidx.work:work-rxjava2:2.8.1")
```

Note: If you use Firebase admob or another library related to Firebase then update the version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
```